# Debugging xUnit tests in .NET Core and Visual Studio Code

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I'm on a Mac, running .NET Core 1.0 and Visual Studio Code.

I have a console project and a test project. I have setup launch.json so that I can debug the console project.

How do I set up a launch configuration that launches my unit tests and attaches the debugger?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See [Tyler Long's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38372628/5156709). The steps below are not required in the newest versions of Visual Studio Code :)

---

I made [a repository](https://github.com/NickolasAcosta/netcore-xunit-debugging) to demonstrate.

First off, the only way I could get the debugger to hit the test was to add a file, Program.cs, take control of the entry point from xUnit, and manually add code to test. It's not ideal, but I imagine you aren't going to be doing this very often, and it's easy to flip it back to normal.

#### Program.cs:

```
using System;
namespace XUnitDebugging
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new TestClass();
            test.PassingTest();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter text...");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Next, in project.json add the following:

```
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "debugType": "portable"
  },
```

#### project.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "testRunner": "xunit",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "debugType": "portable"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "xunit": "2.2.0-beta2-build3300",
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will allow you to debug an xUnit unit test project.

Comment: It works for me. By the way, you don't need to comment/uncomment `"testRunner": "xunit"` and it just works.

Comment: I'll accept this answer since it was correct at the time I posted the question - there was indeed no polished way of debugging unit tests in VSCode 1.2.

Comment: Is this available on VSCode for MacOS as well?

Answer (score 188):

If you install the latest software and library, it is super easy to debug:

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, just click "debug test" and debug it!

Comment: How do you debgu and/or run all tests?

Comment: @gerrard00 I don't know how to debug all tests. To run all tests, `dotnet test`.

Comment: just to add that in your test project's project.json you may want to add this to your buildOptions section. "debugType": "portable". This will solve the problem that "No Symbol loaded for this document"

Comment: Does this work with nunit tests?  My install isn't showing this option.

Comment: @RyanWalls Frankly speaking I don't know. I am afraid that there isn't very seemless integration for NUnit in VSCode (yet). And that's the reason why I learned xUnit.

Comment: Did you have to add a launch config to launch.json before the debug test link shows up?

Comment: @WarrenP I remember that the editor prompt me to create a launch config file. I don't remember I changed anything in that file manually.

Comment: What configuration does this debug use? Because call too Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() gives me root folder and not the folder where my Startup.cs is located I am serving my images with custom file provider which uses this information.

Comment: its visible for me but nothing happens when i click on "debug test"

Comment: Did you install any plugin, I am Not getting like this in new vscode. Also the code has no json files to configure

Comment: @Saravanan Yes install this plugin: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode

Comment: That was not easy to find.  To make that "debug test" link show up, you need to right-mouse click the test section, select "Run Code" then those links will show up.  Then you can click the "debug test" section afterward.

Comment: I doesn't work for me with "csproj". According to official Microsoft page: "During the development of the .NET Core tooling, an important design change was made to no longer support project.json files and instead move the .NET Core projects to the MSBuild/csproj format."

Comment: Comment by [user Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3319644/daniel): " you can debug all tests in a similar way by using the context menu entry 'Debug All Tests' at the class containing the tests"

Comment: is there any difference in Linux version of VSCode. I have the latest deb and also latest version of C# extension but still that Debug button is not appearing.

Comment: If you're not seeing the option to run/debug your tests, make sure VSCode has Code Lens enabled. It's the thing about functions that says how many times it's been used, I purposely disabled this but you need it for xunit.

Comment: I wasn't able to see the Run / Debug Test options until I made my projects part of a solution and added the Test Project to the solution (on linux, fwiw).  https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/3753#issuecomment-624176681

Comment: Only problem with this answer, is some people hate code lens for all the other stuff  it shows that I don't need or want to see

Comment: the 'latest library'?  please explain.  I have the latest, and don't see that option.

Answer (score 12):

I was able to run the debugger on an entire xUnit project with the following *complicated* launch config.  I inspected the calls the "debug test" link (in @Tyler Long response above) was making through the C# (Omnisharp) [VS Code extension](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/b7ce4dc88defa49196debefb291ccf4a46c0dc65/src/features/dotnetTest.ts#L57-L73) to figure this out.  Things to note: 1) you must provide the *absolute* path to the dotnet program 2) you must provide the *absolute* path (i.e. you cannot use `~/` or `$HOME/`) to .nuget/packages folders 3) in the example below, the name of my test project namespace is `Tests`.  Once you have this launch config in place, you can place breakpoints(s), launch the debugger using this config and it should hit all the breakpoints.

```json
{
  "name": "Debug xunit tests",
  "type": "coreclr",
  "request": "launch",
  "preLaunchTask": "build",
  "program": "/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet",
  "args": [
    "exec",
    "--runtimeconfig",
    "${workspaceRoot}/AppNameHere/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/AppNameHere.runtimeconfig.json",
    "--depsfile",
    "${workspaceRoot}/AppNameHere/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/AppNameHere.deps.json",
    "--additionalprobingpath",
    "/Users/jdoe/.nuget/packages",
    "/Users/jdoe/.nuget/packages/dotnet-test-xunit/1.0.0-rc2-build10015/lib/netcoreapp1.0/dotnet-test-xunit.dll",
    "${workspaceRoot}/AppNameHere/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/AppNameHere.dll",
    "-namespace",
    "Tests"
  ],
  "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
  "stopAtEntry": false
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great! One minor thing that I did to make this a little easier to share with coworkers is to add a symbolic link to the .nuget directory in the root of the workspace: `ln -s ~/.nuget`, and then to change `/Users/jdoe` to `${workspaceRoot}` -- It's not ideal, but it's a one-time setup. (Also, remember to ignore `.nuget/` in your VCS config!!)

Comment: @Brady Holt how were you able to inspect the "debug test" calls?  Trying to replicate this but my omnisharp extension is using a different package than the one specified.

Comment: 1) I had to put AppNameHere.dll param immediately after `exec` for it to work properly.  2) Instead of symbolic links or hard coded paths, you could put a setting in your user settings file and reference it: `${config:tasks.nugetPath}/dotnet-xunit/2.3.1/lib/netcoreapp2.0/dotnet-xunit.dll`  3) I didn't have the `dotnet-test-xunit`, so I used the path referenced in #2.  4) After all of that, my debug window outputs `The program '[10500] dotnet.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).` immediately and I don't hit any breakpoints.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

[Tyler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38372628/3982001) of clicking the `debug test` code lens icons is the easiest way of debugging a single test.

A way of testing all unit tests would be to add `while(!Debugger.IsAttached) Thread.Sleep(500);` inside the tests. This will make the tests wait until you attach a debugger.

```csharp
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class SomeClassTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void ShouldDoTest()
        {
            while(!Debugger.IsAttached) Thread.Sleep(500);
            Assert.That(true, Is.True);
        }

        [Test]
        public void ShouldDoTest2()
        {
            while(!Debugger.IsAttached) Thread.Sleep(500);
            Assert.That(true, Is.True);
        }
    }
}
```

This then allows you to attach the Visual Studio Code debugger to the running testhost.dll. Simple select `.NET Core Attach` and then the `dotnet testhost.dll`.

[image: Debug .NET Core Attach]

Answer (score 1):

You can use C# Dev Kit, and use the command `Test: Debug`. This will present a range of options including debugging tests at the Cursor, All tests, Failed tests.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** A quick fix (per [Cyrille Belfort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74196649/1958726)):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. Search for and select *OmniSharp: Select Project*
3. Select the test project
4. <kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

**Original answer:** To have OmniSharp detect both projects without having to switch between them, you can create a solution.

1. Create a solution:

   ```
   cd YourProjectRootDirectory
   dotnet new sln --name YourSolutionName
   ```
2. Add your projects:

   ```
   dotnet sln add .\src\YourProject.csproj
   dotnet sln add .\test\YourProject.Tests.csproj
   ```
3. Reload VS Code:

   1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
   2. Search for and select *Developer: Reload window*
   3. <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Select the solution:

   1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
   2. Search for and select *OmniSharp: Select Project*
   3. Select your solution
   4. <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Before:

[image: A test method with only "0 references" above it]

After:

[image: A test method with "0 references | Run Test | Debug Test" above it]

[Thanks to @lp for the comment suggesting this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38146011/debugging-xunit-tests-in-net-core-and-visual-studio-code#comment109942147_38372628)

Answer (score 0):

@Eric Eskildsen, Helped me solve for myself

To be noted I only used Step 4 and selected the csproj I was working on rather than building a solution.

The strange thing is only those CodeLens test link seemed affected.
Omnisharp hints and/or inlay hints are working throughout the workspace.

Comment: Thanks—added this to my answer (crediting you).