# How to run all tests in Visual Studio Code

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, .net-core, xunit.net

The latest version of VS Code already provides an easy way of running a single test as pointed on [Tyler Long's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38372628/1140754) to the question [Debugging xunit tests in .NET Core and Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38146011/1140754).

However, I am looking how can I run **all tests** contained in a test suite class in VS Code (without debug)?

The only way I found was adding to `launch.json` a specific configuration as the following one, but which I can only run in debug (I would like to run it without debug):

```json
{
  "name": ".NET Core Xunit tests",
  "type": "coreclr",
  "request": "launch",
  "preLaunchTask": "build",
  "program": "/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet",
  "args": ["test"],
  "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/test/MyProject.Tests",
  "externalConsole": false,
  "stopAtEntry": false,
  "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
}
```

Answer (score 26):

You can run all tests in a project by executing `dotnet test` on the terminal. This is handy if you already have the terminal open, but you can add it to Visual Studio code as well.

If you press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> to open the Command Palette and type "test", you can run the **Run Test Task** command. By default, this doesn't do anything, but you can edit `tasks.json` to tell it how to run `dotnet test` for you:

**tasks.json**

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "command": "dotnet",
  "isShellCommand": true,
  "args": [],
  "tasks": [
    {
      "taskName": "build",
      "args": [ ],
      "isBuildCommand": true,
      "showOutput": "silent",
      "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    },
    {
      "taskName": "test",
      "args": [ ],
      "isTestCommand": true,
      "showOutput": "always",
      "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    }
  ]
}
```

These two task definitions will link the **Run Build Task** and **Run Test Task** commands in Visual Studio Code to `dotnet build` and `dotnet test`, respectively.

Comment: This seems to have changed in VS Code v 1.14.

Answer (score 16):

To build on GraehamF's answer, the configuration required in `tasks.json` for dotnet 2.0 is different.

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        ...
    },
    {
        "label": "test",
        "command": "dotnet",
        "type": "shell",
        "group": "test",
        "args": [
            "test",
            "${workspaceFolder}/testprojectfolder/testprojectname.csproj"
        ],
        "presentation": {
            "reveal": "silent"
        },
        "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    }
]
```

I found that when Visual Studio and VS Code are both installed, putting the csproj reference in the command property (as in GraehamF's answer) resulted in Visual Studio being opened rather than the tests being run within VS Code.

(I would have put this in a comment, but I do not have enough reputation points.)

Comment: Would this work with multiple test projects? I ran dotnet test (we use nunit) and it outputted errors for each project that wasn't a test project - but ran the tests in the test projects fine as well. That sucks, right?

Answer (score 8):

To run tests in Visual Studio (VS) Code, you need to add a `tasks.json` file to the `.vscode` directory (if you don't already have it). Then configure your test task as follows:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            ... // Other tasks
        },
        {
            "label": "test",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "shell",
            "args": [
                "test",
                "${workspaceFolder}/TestProjectName/TestProjectName.csproj"
            ],
            "group": "test",
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile",
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "always",
                "focus": false,
                "panel": "shared",
                "showReuseMessage": true,
                "clear": false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

When you have that saved, run the following command <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> on Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> on Linux and Windows within the VS Code interface then type **Run Test Task**, press `Enter` and select `test`.

> The above configuration should work for the latest Insider and Stable releases of VS Code as at April 2020 (version 1.41).

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Nate Barbettini's answer, but for .Net Core Standard 2.0 (netcoreapp2.0).

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "test",
            "command": "dotnet test path/to/test-project.csproj",
            "type": "shell",
            "group": "test",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "silent"
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```