# Is there an extension for running `mstest` tests in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, mstest

I created a new .NET Core 2.1 solution to learn some new tools. In this solution I have two C# projects: a class library and mstest. I want to run the tests in my `mstest` project in Visual Studio Code. However, I do not see a way to do this.

I looked through the Visual Studio Code [extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=test&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance), however, I didn't see an extension that targets mstest projects. Am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run all tests in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41958510/how-to-run-all-tests-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running .NET Core it looks like you can run unit tests by just typing dotnet tests.  There is more documentation [MS Docs .NET Unit Testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-dotnet-test).  But if you wanted to run MS Tests you don't need Visual Studio to do so it comes with its own console, or CLI.  Its documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/ms182469(v=vs.90)) and more about the command line tool [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx)