# vscode on osx not discovering dotnetcore xunit tests

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, .net-core, xunit

I have a dotnetcore solution containing a service layer project along with a test project for this service layer.

According to  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38146011/debugging-xunit-tests-in-net-core-and-visual-studio-code/38372628#38372628) SO post from 2016 vscode should be able to automatically detect my xunit tests and allow me to debug and run them individually.
However, when i open file containing an xunit [fact], i am not seeing any options that allow me to debug the test: [image]

I think this may be related to the new .csproj structure of dotnet core, instead of the old json format.

I am able to debug the tests in visual studio 2017 on windows, any way to also enable this on vscode for osx?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the following references in order for VS to detect your tests. This is how your `project.json` should look like:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "xunit": "2.2.0",
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-*",
    "xunit.runner.visualstudio": "2.2.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.DotNet.InternalAbstractions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk": "15.0.0",
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.1.1"
        }
      },
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.4",
        "portable-net451+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "testRunner": "xunit"
}
```

The important part is that you have to have the `testrunner` set as `xunit` and also add the `Microsoft.DotNet.InternalAbstractions` as well.

I found this after struggling for an hour or so...

Answer (score 0):

No action on this thread for two months, so here's my contribution.

Are you running `dotnet test` from the test directory?  I had the same problem (in VSCode on OSX), naively expecting tests to run from the solution directory.  They don't.

Comment: i decided to use project rider for osx. I might try it later on so thanks for your suggestion.