# How do I do I execute tests in Debug mode using .Net Core and VSCode?

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code, .net-core

How do I execute tests in Debug mode using .Net Core and VSCode?

I am currently running the following on the command line:

```
dotnet Test
```

However, this is not executing the tests in debug mode.

Do I attach a debugger?

If so... How?

Comment: Does your use case require running the tests from the command line, or are you open to running the tests from VSCode?

Comment: What do you see when you run `dotnet --version`?

Comment: I'm open to running tests from VSCode. 2.0.0-preview3-006887

Comment: Does your use case require running *all* the tests at once, or are you open to running one test at a time in debug mode?

Comment: Debug one specific test.

Comment: Are you using xunit or mstest for testing?

Comment: It appears that VSCode does not support F# debugging at this time. See https://github.com/ionide/ionide-vscode-fsharp/issues/387 and  https://github.com/ionide/ionide-vscode-fsharp/issues/408

Comment: Do you need to use a debugger or do you need to run the tests under a debug configuration?

Comment: Using NUnit and need a debugger

Comment: For what it is worth... I use xUnit, .NET Core, F#, VS Code. The xUnit template includes a Main function. The "dotnet test" ignores that function. But, I can call one of the tests from the Main function... and press F5 to step through it. That's what I'm doing.

Comment: Thanks @Wally - That technique worked for me.

Comment: Our C# friends currently have a convenient "debug test" link that appears in the VS Code editor: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38146011

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. If necessary, convert the test project to be a console app, instead of a library. For example, use

`<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>`

2. Add a main method or function.

```
    // C#
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
```

```
    // F#
    module Program =
        [<EntryPoint>]
        let main(args: string[]) = 0
```

3. In the main, call the test that you want to debug.
4. Run the console application in the debugger (usually pressing F5).

This should have no effect on running `dotnet test`.

Comment: I didn't have to convert the Test project to a Console. I just added a main function.

Comment: @ScottNimrod What is the TargetFramework of your project?

Comment: netcoreapp1.1 - https://github.com/Lambda-Cartel/Nikeza/tree/master/Server/Nikeza.Test