# How to debug non-test project in visual studio code with Xunit

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How can i debug the project wen i am running the test class.I did in this in visual studio 2017 but i do not know how to do this in visual studio code. I am using XUnit for testing. How to do this. Any one try to help me.

Thank you...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debugging xUnit tests in .NET Core and Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38146011/debugging-xunit-tests-in-net-core-and-visual-studio-code)

Comment: There is no project.json in my project. I have only project.csproj file. Is this right place to add the code.

Comment: Tyler Long's answer seemed to cover newer version that doesn't have `project.json`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38372628/232566